# wpdb prepare: passing varible number of fields as second argument

Tags: wpdb

As i want to manage the NULL fields in my db and wordpress functions doesn't allow to do so, i will need to dynamically generate a query depending on the situation. The problem is that i don't know how to pass a variable number of fields as second argument! this is what i've been tr but it returns an "Empty query" error:

```
if ($a == '') {
    $fields = 'b, c';
    $placeholders = "'%s', '%s'";
    $vars = $b . ', ' . c;
} else {
    $fields = 'a, b, c';
    $placeholders = "'%s', '%s', '%s'";
    $vars = $a . ', ' .$b . ', ' . c;
}
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (' . $fields . ') VALUES (' . $placeholders . ')';
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $vars));
```

is there any way to do so (even using $wpdb->insert)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an array for your `$vars`, so replace

```
$vars = $a . ', ' .$b . ', ' . c;
```

with

```
$vars = array( $a, $b, $c );
```

But I would rather recommend you to use the `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format )` method. Then your code example could look like this:

```
$data   = array( 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c );
$format = array( '%s', '%s', '%s' );

if( empty( $a ) )
{
    $data   = array_slice( $data,   1, 2 );
    $format = array_slice( $format, 1, 2 ); 
} 

$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
```

Comment: if i understood your question, there's an error: it should be `$data   = array_slice( $data,   1, 2 );` and `$format = array_slice( $format, 1, 2 );` right? as if $a is at the first position, if it is missing the slice should start from position 1 right?

Comment: @Mariano, yes you're correct, I was thinking about `a` and `b` but you wanted `b` and `c`. I updated the answer.

Comment: that's ok, it means i correctly understood your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying (almost) to construct the whole query and then pass it through `prepare`.  That is not right.

1. `prepare` works more like `sprintf`.or `vsprintf`
2. Don't quote your replacement formats-- these `$s`. That won't work.
3. The second argument to `prepare` can be an array, and that is what I'd use here.

Try this:

```
$a = $b = $c = "abc";
if ($a == '') {
    $fields = 'b, c';
    $placeholders = "'%s', '%s'";
    $vars = $b . ', ' . c;
} else {
    $fields = 'a, b, c';
    $placeholders = "%s, %s, %s";
    $vars = array($a,$b,$c);
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (' . $fields . ') VALUES (' . $placeholders . ')';
var_dump($query);
var_dump($wpdb->prepare($query, $vars));
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! anyway i will try birgire's solution as it uses the wpdpb insert function and it seems to me to be a more "official" way (i know they're both official)

Comment: Choose the method you prefer, of course, but I never use the 'insert' wrapper-- helper function overkill, frankly.